# Runing spark streaming job using or authenticating two keytab (Hadoop and Kafka kerberos)

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kerberos, confluent-platform

We have Secure Hadoop cluster (XYZ.keytab) and Secure KAFKA (kafka_c.keytab).

How can we run spark streaming job passing both keytabs to spark2-submit command ? I tried running below command but its not working. Any workarround?

```
spark2-submit 
  --master yarn 
  --deploy-mode cluster 
  --conf 'spark.app.name=Job_Name_Dev' 
  --num-executors 3 
  --executor-cores 5 
  --executor-memory 2G 
  --driver-memory 2G 
  --keytab /home/XYZ.keytab 
  --principal XYZ@E.ABC.ORG  
  --files /home/kafka/kafka_c.keytab,/home/kafka/jaas.conf,/home/kafka/krb5.conf 
  --driver-java-options '-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf  -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf' --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf' 
  --class StreamingApp /home/jars/kafsparkstream.jar
```

How can we authenticate both secure services while running spark streaming job ?

Comment: how can we authenticate both secure services while running spark streaming job ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use hadoop and kafka keytab in same spark submit command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409926/how-to-use-hadoop-and-kafka-keytab-in-same-spark-submit-command)